# Wordpress + fancybox . How to list wordpress posts and use fancybox to display the post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fancybox

Im new to wordpress and also javascript and need a bit of help from you experts.

Im trying to make a wordpress page where it contains a slider that shows all the post, but then when you click it, it'll display the image of the post (featured image) as a popup(fancybox), I do not want it to go to the post URL.

I tried playing around with fancybox but still unable to do it. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

[**Read more**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

You can show those posts in the fancy box easily. In the fancy box plugin, Make the query and retrive posts data where the link is created. There you can add an  tag

Comment: this is only going to display the posts right? i wanted to click on the posts Title(link) and open the content of it inside  a fancybox.

Comment: yeah you can get the post name, link, title etc. check the link I have provided.

Comment: thanks for shading some light on this. so how can i actually link the fancybox to the post links dynamically? so that i do not have to do it every single time for every single post?

Comment: if the fancy box plugin, Make the query and retrive posts data where the link is created. There you can add an <a> tag

Comment: thanks man. you're pointing me to the right direction. cheers

Comment: i have one more problem. i put the link in the fancy box but the only link/post that opens in fancybox is just one link. what is wrong? code is below

            <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
 <!--<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>-->
        <a id="various3" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: i got the correct one for each. but fancybox will only function on the latest post link . the older ones will open in a new window, not in fancybox.

Comment: compare the two links and see. Most probably I might be missing a fancy box class or something. Check whether all links are identical.

Comment: got the solution, just changed the id to class tag. thanks for your help man. i can't up your help since i dont have 15 rep.